# How to insert an adjacent element if child element contains specific text?

Tags: javascript

I'm inserting an element with the following code:

```
var descriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".product-item-info");

function showDescription() {
  descriptions.forEach(description => {
      description.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class='description'>Some text</div>");
   
  });
}

showDescription();
```

This works well. But how do I check if a child of `.product-item-info` contains specific text, and if so then *not* add the markup to said element?

I know how to do this with jQuery.

Edit: change `afterend`  to `beforeend`

Comment: A brute force approach might be `description.innerText.includes( 'you sample text' )`.

Comment: *"I know how to do this in jQuery but looking for a Vanilla JS solution only."* What you're looking for is a [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) solution. You're using JavaScript either way. JavaScript != DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it with the DOM the same way you do it with jQuery, it's just you have to do a bit that jQuery does behind the scenes in your own code: Seeing if elements contain that text. There's no real shortcut, you just have to look at the text of the element:

```
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".product-item-info");

function showDescription() {
    for (const description of descriptions) {
        if (!description.textContent.includes("Some text")) {
            description.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class='description'>Some text</div>");
        }
    }
}

showDescription();
```

(The optional chaining handles the case where a description doesn't have a next element sibling.)

Comment: My mistake - should have been beforeend. So a child of .product-item-info can contain the targeted text, if so, dont add the element